# Cumulative distribution function on uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

For $l>0$, $X$ is a random variable according to the uniform distribution on the interval $[0, l].$

At this time, the probability density function $f(x)$ of $X$ is

$f_X(x)=  \cases{0 & if $x<0$\\
        \frac{1}{l} & if $ 0 \le x \le l$\\
      0 & if $x > l$}
$

The length of the shorter interval obtained by dividing the following  interval $[0,l]$ into 2 at random  is expressed by a random variable $Y$.

The length of the longer interval obtained by randomly dividing  interval $[0,l]$ into two parts is expressed by a random variable $Z$.

Find the distribution function $F_y $ of Y. Find the distribution function
$ F_Z$ of Z.

$f_Y(x)=  \cases{0 & if $x<0$\\
        \frac{1}{l/2} & if $ 0 \le x <\frac{l}{2}$\\
      0 & if $x \le l$}
$

$f_Z(x)=  \cases{0 & if $x<0$\\
\frac{1}{l/2} & if $ 0 \le x <1/2$\\
        \frac{4}{(2-l)l} & if $ l/2 \le x <1$\\
      0 & if $x \le l$}
$

I'm not sure, am I correct? And after this, do I just need to integrate it to find $F_Y$?

Comment: I don't know how to interpret your function $f$. It seems to be a function of $x$ and $\ell$. On a closer look, however, it is not a function because if $x=0$ and $\ell=1$ its value is 1 (according to the second line) and 0 (according to the third line).

Comment: Your $f(x)$ does not make sense if $X\sim U(0,1)$. And you have $Y=\min (X,1-X), Z=\max(X,1-X)$.

Comment: @GerhardS.@StubbornAtom im sorry i have so many typo, i fixed it , i also dont quite understand what partition into two in uniform distribution

Comment: What is the use of $l$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom i  edit my post again,  l is for interval $[0,l]$

Answer (score 1):

You are not quite correct, but not far away.

Apart from your typographical confusion between $1$ and $l$, you have some inequalities the wrong way round and some major issues in the density function for $Z$: it cannot be less than $l/2$ since it is the longer of the two pieces, and in fact it has a uniform distribution between $l/2$ and $l$. I think you should have something like

$f_Y(x)=  \cases{0 & if $x<0$\\
        \frac{1}{l/2} & if $ 0 \le x \le \frac{l}{2}$\\
      0 & if $x \gt l/2$}
$

$f_Z(x)=  \cases{0 & if $x<0$\\
0 & if $ 0 \le x \le l/2$\\
        \frac{1}{l/2} & if $ l/2 \lt x \le l$\\
      0 & if $x \gt l$}
$

Then, as you suggest, you should integrate to get the cumulative distribution functions

Comment: thankyou so much but why in the $f_Z$ for $ 0<=x<=l/2$ must be 0?

Comment: @devss "The length of the longer interval obtained by randomly dividing  interval $[0,l]$ into two parts is expressed by a random variable $Z$" so $Z$ is the longer of the two parts and must be at least $l/2$

Comment: but the two of the partition are completely different part? so for cumulative we dont need to sum the short and large partition?

Comment: @devss The distribution of $Z$ is the same as the distribution of $l-Y$ from their definitions. Similarly $0 \le Y \le l/2$ and $l/2 \le Z \le l$